# How can I rewrite image path via htaccess?

Tags: image, .htaccess, path, url-rewriting

I have two websites e.g.,

- www.example1.com
- www.example2.com

example1 is already up and has all the images I need to put in my example2 website.

i want to get all images from example1 to put in my example2 website e.g.,

www.example1.com/media/img/image1.jpg <-- get this image and put in
www.example1.com/media/img/image2.jpg

I want this done so that I don't have to copy all images from example1 directory to example2

Thank you all... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htacces. Then put this code in your .htaccess under DOCUMENT_ROOT:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^media/img/ http://www.example1.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC]
```